# Parse an object which consist of outer string

Tags: arrays, json, string, laravel, local-storage

I have an issue with laravel storage::getdata(); as the output returns an objcet which consist of outer st .The output is as follows.

```
    $content = storage::getdata();

string(4794) "stdClass Object (
[GetNewTransactionsResult] => 0
[xmlTransactions] =>0
  )"
```

The string(4794) " " is a varying string whose value will change depends upon the inner content.

Here the object is inside a string so that `$content->GetNewTransactionsResult` will throw an error

> "Trying to get property 'GetNewTransactionsResult' of non-object"
>   .Please help me to remove the outer string .

Thanks and regards
Shabin

Comment: Try `unserialize($content)`